# UIScrollView - All the direction - is it advisable?

Tags: ios, ipad

I want to implement the UIScrollView in horizontally and vertically. (Move Top, Bottom,right,left). is it good for use the app at the user end ? is it advisable one?

Is Apple accept this type of implementation? Please Guide Me. THanks in advance.

Comment: Why not if it suits the purpose of your application?

Comment: Most prominent example: Maps.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can certainly make your scroll view scrollable in both directions, and there's no reason that Apple should mind -- after all, they built that capability into UIScrollView, and plenty of apps (including their own) make use of it.

Whether your interface will work well for your users is a separate problem. The mere fact that you have a 2D scroller shouldn't hurt, but it obviously wouldn't work so well if the content is inherently 1-dimensional. For example, a table view should usually scroll only vertically.

Comment: I would add something: inform the user that they can scroll both ways (if it's not absolutely evident). There's nothing more frustrating that discovering long after having used the app that you could do more than what you thought. Even worse, they may send a bad review because they missed something, because they didn't know they could scroll both ways.